# Defining relation in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, datamodel

I'm having trouble defining a relationship in CakePHP. I have the following datamodel:

```
 +--------------+
 |  Course      |
 +--------------+
 | other fields |
 | T_id         |---+
 | A_id         |-+ |     +--------------+
 +--------------+ | |     | Item         |
                  | |     +--------------+
 +--------------+ +-------| id           |
 |  Paragraph   | | |     | other fields |
 +--------------+ | |     +--------------+
 | other fields | | |
 | T_id         |-+ |
 | A_id         |---+
 +--------------+
```

Where there are 2 tables that have a relation with one other table.
Moreover: every one of the Course and Paragraph have two "Item". I thought I would define T-id and A_id as hasOne with Item, but CakePHP does not seem to agree on this :-)
hasOne feels semantiaclly correct, but... it does not work (The CRUD-generated code does not give me a drop-down to select the Item. It does create a dropdown, butit is empty.

How to define the model, so that CakePHP understands that those two key-fields in each table each point to one Item? (So, in total there would be 4 records in Item if there is 1 chapter and 1 paragraph.)

At the moment, I have this:

```
'AItem' => array(
  'className' => 'Item',
  'foreignKey' => 'id',
  'conditions' => array('a_item_id = Item.id'),
  'fields' => '',
  'order' => ''
)
```

the SQL used to generate the Course-tabel:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `courses` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a_item_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `t_item_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  foreign key (a_item_id) references items(id) on delete cascade,
  foreign key (t_item_id) references items(id) on delete cascade
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

regards,

Paul

Comment: genertaing the code yourself or trying to generate from Cake-Bake-Console

Comment: I'm trying to generate it by using the bake-console, but apartently my model is not correct.

Comment: are you creating in PHP-MY-ADMIN using INNODB-Engine

Comment: created using plain SQL; added the SQL to the question

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing something like the following

**Item Model**

```
class Item extends AppModel {

    public $hasOne = array(
        'CourseA' => array(
            'className' => 'Course',
            'foreignKey' => 'item_a_id',
            'type' => 'INNER'
        ),
        'CourseB' => array(
            'className' => 'Course',
            'foreignKey' => 'item_b_id',
            'type' => 'INNER'
        ),
        'ParagraphA' => array(
            'className' => 'Paragraph',
            'foreignKey' => 'item_a_id',
            'type' => 'INNER'
        ),
        'ParagraphB' => array(
            'className' => 'Paragraph',
            'foreignKey' => 'item_b_id',
            'type' => 'INNER'
        )
    );
}
```

**Course Model**

```
class Course extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'ItemA' => array(
            'className' => 'Item',
            'foreignKey' => 'item_a_id',
            'type' => 'INNER'
        ),
        'ItemB' => array(
            'className' => 'Item',
            'foreignKey' => 'item_b_id',
            'type' => 'INNER'
        )
    );
}
```

**Paragraph Model**

```
class Paragraph extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'ItemA' => array(
            'className' => 'Item',
            'foreignKey' => 'item_a_id',
            'type' => 'INNER'
        ),
        'ItemB' => array(
            'className' => 'Item',
            'foreignKey' => 'item_b_id',
            'type' => 'INNER'
        )
    );
}
```

This doesn't follow strictly your database table layout, I personally feel having more descriptive fields is better than a_id, having item_a_id is descriptive enough to show another developer this field links to an item record.

This expects that the Course and Paragraph tables have the fields "item_a_id" and "item_b_id" set as INT/MEDIUMINT etc .

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. The reason I did not do this is that it "feels" the wrong way around: the Items "belong" to the Course, not the other way around. And I thought it would/should work as I tried to do it. And I would never from the Item "upwards" try to find which Course they belong to, so this aproach defines 4 relations that in my viewof the datamodel are not there.Would it be possible for you to describe your reasoning? (I know I ask a difficult question in this, but just trying to really understand what you are doing :-) )

Comment: It appears I misunderstood the original question, my apologies. I will update my answer shortly to reflect the question. I was under the impression that Course would have different two items associated to one record and Paragraph would have two different items associated to one record.

Comment: Well, this is the case. Every Course needs two Items, and every Chapter as well. The thing is dat I did not think that Items need "to be aware" of the relationship they might have with either a Course or a Paragraph. (There might even be more Objects that need items, so I wnat Items to be as simple as possible

Comment: Also you mention that the Item belongs to the course and not the other way around, for this to be so with Cake ORM you will need item have a course_id or course_a_id (belongsTo tables always have the foreign key field). 

With my above example if you did $this->Course->find('first', array('contain' => 'ItemA', 'ItemB')); You will get results like such:

[Course] => array(
 .. data
)
[ItemA] => array(
 .. data from Course[item_a_id]
)
[ItemB] => array(
 .. data from Course[item_b_id]
)

I'm a little confused by what you want at this point, but maybe this is right after all?

Comment: Thank you for your patience! :-) What I'm trying to achieve is for multiple (Course and Paratgraph, but there will be more) Models to have two items linked to them. From the Model Course etc I want to be able to retrieve the Items that belong to them. What I would not like (but if there is no other way, then of course it will be that way) is for Item to contain different fields for every Table that needs an Item. I would think that leads to overhead and many fields not being used.

Comment: No problem. The example I gave you originally will do what you want, I have used something similar in my current project and it works a treat.

I think the terminology on the associations is what is confusing you, keep item_a_id, item_b_id in your courses, paragraphs and any other tables with 2x items. You don't want items to have course_a_id, course_b_id, paragraph_a_id, paragragh_b_id and so on which is what you get if Item belongsTo Model. HTH

Comment: The alternative here would be to use hasAndBelongsToMany and have the following join tables: courses_items (id, course_id, item_id), items_paragraphs (id, item_id, paragraph_id).

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49564/discussion-between-hellospeakman-and-paul-wiegers)